# TypeError: (0, _reactNavigation.default) is not a function. React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am using React Navigation Version 4 and after setting my navigations and all screens and run the code I am facing the following issue:

**TypeError: (0, _reactNavigation.default) is not a function.**

My Routes.Js is -

```
import React from 'react';
import createAppContainer from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { Drawer } from './Drawer';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import InitialScreen from '../screens/InitialScreen';
import LogoutScreen from '../screens/LogoutScreen';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Drawer: { 
            screen: Drawer
        },
        LoginScreen: {
            screen: LoginScreen
        },
        LogoutScreen: {
            screen: LogoutScreen
        }
        InitialScreen: {
            screen: InitialScreen
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'InitialScreen',
        headerMode: "none"
    }
)

const App = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default App;
```

and Index.js is -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Text, Drawer } from 'native-base';
import App from './config/Routes';
import AppHeader from './components/Header/Header';

export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        const { globalContainer } = styles;
        return (
            <App 
                style={ globalContainer } 
                navigation={this.props.navigation}>
            </App>
        )
    }
}
```

Any help??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears from the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/hello-react-navigation) that it should be a named import, not a default.

```js
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```

Please read the docs. It's also a good first place to look when debugging.

Comment: A similar error is also observed and fixed when importing connect from react-redux. The correct way to import would be `import { connect } from react-redux`